# How to get rid of margin

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Trying to understand CSS. I have deconstructed my entire webpage to a few simple elements because I cannot figure out why there is a huge right margin taking up the entire right side of my screen on a div. element. So, I have this yellow box, I want to make its position relative because in actuality it is going to be a side navigation menu. Again, for testing purposes I broke everything down. The contents inside the box will have position absolute because it will be easier to move those inner contents around and position them within the box how I want them. Side note: this is not going to be a responsive design. Anyway, when I make the yellow container box position relative, in chrome developer tools, it shows a massive right margin stemming from the box. I have set the margin on all four sides to 0. I even moved he box away from the left side of the screen to show that the top, bottom, and left sides have no margin value. Only the right somehow makes a margin. This is imperative because I cannot get to put my main content to the side of this box as the margin encompasses whole screen. Thanks. Oh… and also, when I make its position absolute it fixes this everything, but I need it to be relative for the inner items that will have absolute positioning.

```css
.yellow-container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-container"></div>
```

Comment: is your yellow box inside a container? because i assume you have everything relative underneath eachother, and the "margin" space you see is chrome calculating space that isnt used but also cant be used since you didnt secify that multiple relative objects can sit besides eachother. as show in this fiddle. you cant just have multiple relative objects filling space left to right https://jsfiddle.net/ybk2Lzp3/

Comment: as shown in this fiddle. adding `display: flex` to the "parent", in this case the body it does fill the left to right space https://jsfiddle.net/ybk2Lzp3/1/

Comment: what i meant was, the yellow box is a container itself and does not fit inside anything other than the body tag. as i did in another comment, i did set body margin to 0 but to no avail. the contents within the yellow box will be links and text. i plan to make those items positioned absolute. the yellow box itself i wanted to be relative. i was watching a youtuber describe css and he said that in order for absolute to work the container must be relative

Comment: and is the page on the right all in one container or multiple relative items?

Comment: @EnhancedBot This is because a `div` is display `block` by default, which means it takes up a whole line by itself. This margin is showing because you set the width to `200px`, so that right margin is the remaining space taken up because its a block-level element. Set it to `display: inline-block;` and you will see

Comment: you do not share enough of your code to demonstrate your issue, hard to guess where that margin or offset positionning comes from :( I turned your bits of code into a snippet that you may update ;)

Comment: im uncertain by what you mena by "page on the left" if you mean is the yellow box all there is, then yes that it. I only have one html page with that div box nested inside of my body tag. linked to it i have my css sheet with the above css styling and the additional 0 margin body styling as suggested by another commentor

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I think he did share enough code, he is just confused on what block level elements are

Comment: THATS IT, i needed inline-block

Comment: or float:left; ;) You could dig into display:flex or display: grid if you are starting learning

Comment: I didn't want to use float, for reference, im new, obvi. I just learned flexbox, css-grid, css box model, positioning, but apparently theres still som tricks i dont know

Comment: What went wrong with flex or grid ? Plenty of us can help you here with these

Comment: my experience is what went wrong lol. I had a really nice layout using css grid but i struggled nesting it into another grid or flex so that my top navigation bar will sit flush with the top of my grid. I know that description was horrible. should i post it here? AND THANKS BTW

Comment: I see ,you  tried to do a lot at once but got confused in the markup and where the parent was a still flex/grid box or not. It will not take long before it gets clear. :)  have funn learning

Comment: slowly but surely, Thanks again!